# How to create a window like CWnd (MFC) in UWP

Tags: mfc, win-universal-app, cwnd

I have a drawing application written in MFC before, now i consider to upgrade it to universal world by using UWP.
The app structure is like below:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsu1N.png)

which include:
1. App level (MFC code): file management.
2. Drawing lib (MFC code): provide a view (extend CWnd) for drawing to App.
3. Drawing lib (C++ code): engine for drawing.

With UWP, it seems like i can only reuse engine code C++ and start over with App and drawing lib MFC.

The problem is i still cannot found a CWnd equivalent in UWP to create a view for drawing without using XAML. Can anyone have solution?

Thanks,

Comment: All the basic drawing stuff described in the [Draw shapes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280380.aspx) article can as well be done in code behind.

Comment: Custom drawing is currently best handled as if you were building a game. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt282476.aspx